# Bash -1 year from date

Tags: bash, shell

```
Year=`date '+%Y'`
RTRN1=$?
```

This returns the current date in the logs, however i want to return the year before, so instead of this returning 2017 i want 2016.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For GNU `date` utility: use `-d` (`--date`) option to adjust the date:

```
Year=$(date +%Y -d'1 year ago')

echo $Year
2016
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, you got it

Comment: This still returns 2017, suprisingly, without any errors but i need it to return 2016, guessing the 1 year ago doesnt work?

Comment: @Matt: What version of `date` do you have?

Comment: @choroba GNU :)

Comment: I mean `type date` and `date --version`

Comment: @choroba date showed Wed Oct 25 10:27:20 BST 2017, not sure what you mean with date version? it says that its a bad conversion

Answer (score 1):

As we have `bash`, it's possible to use `let`

```
let YEAR=`date +%Y`-1
echo $YEAR
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it still returns 2017. I'm unsure why

Answer (score 1):

You can always capture the year with `date +'%Y'`. You can subtract `1` with the POSIX arithmetic operator, e.g.

```
$ echo $(($(date +%Y) - 1))
2016
```

You can also use the POSIX compliant `expr` math operators, e.g.

```
$ expr $(date +%Y) - 1
2016
```

(**note:** with `expr` you must leave a `space` between the math operator and the values)

The GNU date operator `-d` with `'1 year ago'` will work as specified in the comments and other answer, along with `let dt=$(date +%Y)-1; echo $dt` as specified in the other answer (no spaces allowed with `let`).

Of all the choices, if I didn't have GNU `date`, I'd pick the POSIX arithmetic operator `$((...))` with a `date` command substitution minus `1`.

Comment: How would you add this to my current code? Currently it says Parameter value must be 0 thru 72 characters length when i try this. Cheers

Comment: `Year=$(date '+%Y'); Year=$((Year - 1)); echo "Year: $Year` (get rid of the backticks `\`..\`` and use `$(...)` for command substitution - won't change the operation, but it is easier to read). If you wanted to get `2016` into `Year` in one statement, then `Year=$(($(date +%Y) - 1))`